# Filtering a table of both columns and rows conditions in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In the 'Data' sheet, I have a test table. In the 'Result' sheet, I would like to create a table that focuses on a particular value in column A, for example, 'h' (A9).

It should then search the entire row (row 9) in which 'h' occurs and display the content of the columns with data (D9 and F9), while ignoring the empty cells and include the title rows (B1 and C1).

The desired output of the function is a table similar to the one in the 'Example' worksheet.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CPEFLgS0byn7QRvDhaGdQOx43GLgWTHcqGdD_C-Wtw0/edit?usp=sharing)

I've tried to use the 'Filter' function, but I was unable to combine conditions for both columns and rows within a single function.

And somehow I cannot force it to exclude empty cells and include any data "above" and "below" with column names.

Comment: you have not attached any sheet. Could you please double check?

Comment: Sorry for that! Not it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ; choosecols(Data!A1:I18;1;torow(filter(if(len(Data!B:I);column(Data!B:I););Data!A:A="h");1));
     filter(Σ;byrow(choosecols(Σ;sequence(columns(Σ)-1;1;2));lambda(Λ;counta(Λ)<>0))))
```

- *the formula is hard-coded to **`h`** for demo purpose here (`Data!A:A="h"`). You can change it to the cell hosting the **`h`** in your sheet*

[image]

***UPDATED FORMULA*** (`to accommodate checkboxes in Column_A`):

```js
=let(Σ; choosecols(Data!A1:J18;2;torow(filter(IF(LEN(Data!C:J);COLUMN(Data!C:J););Data!B:B=Data!C21);1));
     filter(Σ;byrow(choosecols(Σ;sequence(COLUMNS(Σ)-1;1;2));lambda(Λ;COUNTA(Λ)<>0))))
```

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure it out. OMG, thanx a ton!

Comment: One more thing. If I add a column to the left of column A, e.g. to make easy to use checkboxes there, the result of the function you suggested shifts one column to the right. I.e. by selecting "h" it shows me data from columns 5 and 7, not 4 and 6. Which part of the function syntax is responsible for this shift?

Comment: try the updated formula added to the answer. this part `torow(filter(IF(LEN(Data!C:J);COLUMN(Data!C:J););Data!B:B=Data!C21);1)` is responsible for pulling the 4 & 6

Comment: When I want to use this function in the final file [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WHXPDbMo85lEqTxg73vHndHbJA4d8dyJX4Dwwj9J-cE/edit?usp=sharing) , some of the rows from the 'Data' sheet appear in the 'Output' sheet (where the function is stitched in), even though these rows are empty, i.e. they contain no value apart from the formulas and are not very different from the neighbouring rows that are skipped by the function. For example, if you select a value from the 'Date' sheet in cell B15, the 'Output' rows B4:B6, B10, B12:B35 etc. are empty, which almost look like randomish

Comment: In the **OUTPUT** tab, whatever cells are being returned by the formula are not `TRUE` blank cells. test with the [ISBLANK function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en) & they'll return `FALSE` (https://i.imgur.com/t4HNlER.png). Replace this part of the formula `counta(Λ)<>0` with `COUNTBLANK(Λ)<COLUMNS(Σ)-1` and test

Comment: You are a genious! However, you were able to solve it in just a few moments. Is there anything I can do to repay you? I have been working on this workbook for three weeks and have been stuck on this particular problem for five days, spending several hours each day without finding a solution.

Comment: Its cool:) good luck